# How do i call a function that is using my struct

Tags: c, list, function, struct, typedef

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

typedef struct{
  int zadnji;
  int elementi[MAX];
} Lista;


void ubaci (int x, int pozicija_ubacivanja, Lista *pokLista) 
{
  int pozicija;
  if (pokLista->zadnji >= MAX-1)
    printf("Lista je puna!"); 
  else if ((pozicija_ubacivanja>pokLista->zadnji+1) || (pozicija_ubacivanja<0) )
    printf("Pozicija ne postoji!"); 
  else {
            for (pozicija=pokLista->zadnji; pozicija >= pozicija_ubacivanja; pozicija--)
                 pokLista->elementi[pozicija+1]= pokLista->elementi[pozicija];
            pokLista->zadnji++;
            pokLista->elementi[pozicija_ubacivanja] = x;
           }
}

void obrisi(int pozicija_brisanja, Lista *pokLista) {
  int pozicija;
  if ( (pozicija_brisanja>pokLista->zadnji ) || (pozicija_brisanja<0) )
    printf("Pozicija ne postoji!");
  else {
    pokLista->zadnji--;    
    for (pozicija=pozicija_brisanja; pozicija<=pokLista->zadnji; pozicija++)
       pokLista->elementi[pozicija] = pokLista->elementi[pozicija+1];

  }
}

int trazi (int x, Lista *pokLista) {
  int pozicija;
  for (pozicija=0; pozicija<=pokLista->zadnji; pozicija++)
     if (pokLista->elementi[pozicija] == x) return pozicija;
  return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pozicija_ubacivanja;
    int pozicija_brisanja;
    int i,x,z,pozicija,temp;

    printf("Koji broj ubaciti ?");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("Na koju poziciju ?");
    scanf("%d",&pozicija_ubacivanja);

    ubaci(x,pozicija_ubacivanja,Lista);

    printf("Koju poziciju obrisati ?");
    scanf("%d",&pozicija_brisanja);

    obrisi(pozicija_brisanja, Lista);

    printf("Koju element za pretraziti ?");
    scanf("%d",&z);
    trazi (z, Lista);
    temp = pozicija;
    printf("Pozicija je %d", temp);

    return 0;
}
```

All the functions and `typedef` were provided by a professor, my job is to write main() part of the program. While calling them i get this: [Error] expected expression before 'Lista'

Idk how the arguments are suppose to look when calling these functions.

**pls ignore this**

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
>     It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
>     It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
>     It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

**pls ignore this**

Comment: `Lista` is a type, not a variable. It doesn't belong as-is in the argument list of those function calls in `main`; a *variable* belongs there (or immediate value if appropriate, which it isn't in this case).

Comment: The system told you that your post is mostly code. It is. Please add more explanation. Otherwise maybe reduce the amount of code. An obvious way is to delete the empty lines.

Comment: If you cannot post a question because you get a warning that it is mostly code the solution is **not** to add filler text

Comment: You could for example describe your experience with calling functions with parameters. Did you ever learn to call a function `void something(int AnInt)` Would you call it like `soemthing(int);`? Not? Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a new type called `Lista`, which now represents your struct.

After this section in your code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pozicija_ubacivanja;
    int pozicija_brisanja;
    int i,x,z,pozicija,temp;
```

You can create an instance of `Lista`,

```
Lista lista;
```

Then pass the address of  `lista` (using  `&` ) for example in this function:

```
 ubaci(x,pozicija_ubacivanja,&lista);
```